# Jekyll, How to ignore syntax of space and space 4 times

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm newbie of Jekyll

I'm trying to make a post with markdown in Jekyll

As i know, starting with 4 spaces in a new line makes the line as a code style like bellow.

```
I started with 4 spaces
```

Also in markdown, even though i typed 'enter', it doesn't work.

So every line i type `<br/>` for insert a enter in every single line.

let me summarize what i'm looking for.

1. Even though text starts with 4 spaces, I don't want it could be looked as plain text not code style. So is there any reserved word like `{% ignore from code %}` (it's not existing but what i'm looking for)it ignore 4 spaces from code style.
   and just plain text style
2. Is there any plug-in or built-in way that insert enter without `<br/>`

Comment: Please [ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). I will answer your second question, but I don't understand the first one.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your answer, and also sorry my poor english. I 'll change my question please let me know if you still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

**1. 4 spaces indentation**

There is no way to configure kramdown to ignore 4 space indentation.

But :

```
a line of text followed by an empty newline 

    and an indented line
```

Last line is understood as a code block.

But if you remove the empty newline :

```
a line of text followed by
    an indented line
```

Everything is processed as text

**2. replacing newline by BRs**

You have to configure kramdown from **_config.yml** :

```
kramdown:
  hard_wrap: true
```